# Magento The requested URL /admin was not found on this server. Error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I have installed fresh Magento setup version 1.7. Now I want to access magento admin dashboard it is showing following error in browser.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localmagento17.com Port 80
```

I have check magento database table `core_config_data` but there is no entry for admin/url rows.

[image]

I have changed nothing in database or anywhere, Admin dashboad was used to access before for same installation.

If I need to add entires in database please let me know values for that.

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed with sample data or without

Comment: there is no sample data option  while installation .. I have install magento only not template/theme

Comment: did you tried with sitename.com/index.php/admin

Comment: Try to access admin by **siteurl/index.php/admin**

Comment: Add .htaccess file on root then try to access It works. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Linux Ubuntu open the following file

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

add the following code at the top of the file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

restart the apache server by using the following command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```